# How to increase font size in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to increase the font size for the title of a GUI that was made using javascript. I'm a java script noob but i just wanted to make a few adjustments to the pre-made GUI in a short amount of time. Any help would be appreciated.

```
templateObj.$.ti_widget_plot1.layout.title = 'X-Y Scatter Plot';
```

The code above is what allows me access the title and change the name.

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: What research effort have you made so far? I googled: `How to increase font size in javascript?` and found several answers in the top results, some using JavaScript, others CSS. Pick what ever suits your needs best.

Comment: javascript is not enough here, this language can be used to display in different formats, it can even create PDFs, etc. You should tell us what is this format. If HTML, it would be better to use CSS rule than JS

Comment: Yes the GUI is based on a HTML format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = document.getElementById('text');
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn1.addEventListener('click',function(){
x = window.getComputedStyle(a, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
currentsize = parseFloat(x)
a.style.fontSize = (currentsize + 5) + 'px';
})
btn2.addEventListener('click',function(){
x = window.getComputedStyle(a, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
currentsize = parseFloat(x)
a.style.fontSize = (currentsize - 5) + 'px';
})
```

```html
<button id='btn1'>+</button>
<button id='btn2'>-</button>
<div>
<p id='text'>text content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a starter, I am spelling it out for you. Hope this helps;

**Note:** For styling issues (like yours), please glance through css first before taking up any html related assignment;

```css
#div1 {
  font-size:100%
}
#div2 {
  font-size:200%
}
#div3 {
  font-size:300%
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">this is normal text</div>
<div id="div2">this is BIGG</div>
<div id="div3">this is even more BIGGGGGG</div>
```